# Show custom calender using jquery datepicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

We are using jquery date picker extensively. Now, we want to show custom calender. In our organization we have month starting in different way. say we start october from 23rd of november :)

Is it possible to do with jquery UI datepicker plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a look here? http://reddybrek.com/post/jQuery-UI-date-picker-how-to-set-the-start-date-of-your-second-calendar.aspx